# gitlab-runner randomly runs as root rather than user gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have a simple gitlab-runner setup on its own ubuntu server. It was registered using:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register -n --url https://gitlab.com/ --registration-token {{GITLAB_REGISTRATION_TOKEN}} --executor shell --description "{{GITLAB_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION}}"
```

The only gitlab-runner process (`ps -ef`) that is running is:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
```

My `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` config file contains:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "iouze/landing"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "0530b.....6f9"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

When my CI pipeline triggers, jobs sometimes gets picked up as user gitlab-runner user, in which case they run correctly (as a sheell executor).

But sometimes, it runs as root, in which case it runs as a docker executor, and then gives errors (because the script is running in an unexpected environment).

Why would it run sometimes as root when there is clearly a --user on the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running on gitlab.com and the pipeline jobs were sometimes getting picked up by the shared runners that are already configured there. I disabled the shared runners